# Using get_param in simulink returns an array

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have an S-Function called mxsf. When I run the following command:

```
mxhandle = get_param(mxsf, 'Handle')
```

I get the handle returned of course, but it returns it as [88.0012] instead of 88.0012. I have an in-house .NET library for interfacing with matlab/Simulink, and we have a function that is supposed to get the double of a variable inside Simulink, but it won't work if the double is between brackets. How do I make get_param return the handle without sticking it in an array? It is also worthy to note that this does not always happen (sometimes get_param will get a handle without putting it in an array, but I don't know how to force this). Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found a workaround that seems to always give a straight value. If I put in the actual path to the block and not just mxsf, it returns a double, not an array with one value. So for example, if I do the following:

    mxhandle = get_param('Path_to_subsystem/blockname', 'Handle')

mxhandle will be set as 88.0012 instead of [88.0012] as noted in the above question. However, I am still interested in a solution that will allow me to use the variable I have set my S-Function to.

Comment: @MetalGearSolid: What is the value of the variable `mxsf`?

Comment: mxsf is being set by whatever add_block() returns. I add the block pointing to the S-Function, which causes mxsf to return the model path to the file as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't get add_block() to return the block path as a string, it keeps returning a double (Simulink block handle maybe?). What's your add_block() calling syntax?

My guess is that add_block() is returning a cell array containing the block path and so get_param() returns an array. Try

```
mxhandle = get_param(mxsf{1}, 'Handle')
```